# Are there bounded functions of unbounded variation on finite intervals?

Tags: functional-analysis

Can anyone give an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C_b$ or some other "normal" bounded function space where the variation is unbounded on some finite interval?

Comment: Of course. You will just need to make the function zigzagged enough. The example provided in the answer below $\sin 1/x$ is an obvious example. Besides this, the famous Weierstrass function also furnishes an example, since it is nowhere differentiable (BV funcs are a.e. differentiable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=\sin (\frac 1 x)$ for $0<x \leq 1$, $f(0)=0$ is a standard example.